# Flutter PlayStore Distribution APK is not working, not loading, stuck on splash screen

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, google-play-console

I have downloaded both my `Original apk` and `Distributed apk` directly from playStore console. The `Original apk` works just fine while my `Distributed apk` stuck on the splash screen. `flutter run -v --release` works just fine without any errors.

[image]

I have compared my `Distributed apk` Logcat logs to my `Original apk`, and nothing seems to be different.

## Bottom Line

1. What is the difference between **original** and **distributed** apk?
2. What can cause my app to stuck on splash screen on **distributed** apk?
3. Is there a better way to debug a distributed apk than Logcat?

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same question and problem

Answer (score 0):

Are you running `flutter_secure_storage`?

I was using the React Native equivalent and that was the issue for me. It was throwing for me without me catching it. I think the reason for this is that the stores use the signing key which is the only thing the Distribution key should add? I'm not sure though. Something like this was the fix for me:

```
try {
  await register() // Read something from secure storage and throw
} catch (e) {
  // If reading from expo's SecureStore fails, then clear our storage and try again
  // Without this there can be problems installing the app from Google Play
  await clearStorage()
  await register()
}
```

Comment: Hey @Dara Java thanks for replying. I'm not using `flutter_secure_storage`. Also I dont think it's that cause since all other versions I have uploaded to playStore where just fine, it's the first time it stucked on the splash screen after compiled to distributed apk. In addition I have checked that my signature on playStore is the same on my firebase project.

Comment: Is there anything like that maybe? You can get a play store enabled version of an emulator. I downloaded the app through the play store from a fresh install and it worked. In my case, the issue was down to people who have had an old version, deleted it, and then installed it again